# Refresh Stock Items Screen

Tags: acumatica

I have a problem in Acumatica. I have created a trigger on InventoryItem table to insert the inserted records to my customized table.

The problem is, whenever I try to save new stock items in Acumatica, it does not reflect the correct last-saved data of the stock item. The details in the general settings tab are incorrect. I need to close the screen and reopen to be able to see the correct data.

Can someone please help me with regards to how can I get a refreshed stock item screen immediately after saving. Or is there a bug in Acumatica whenever there is a customized trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked the issue you mentioned about not refreshing the information, but if you **need to forcefully refresh the screen after saving the record**

- Override persist
- call the base action
- create a new instance of graph
- search for the record to set as current of the header cache
- throw new redirect required exception

so the code might look as below [Might require Modification]

```
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(Action persit)
{
 persit();// this will call base Persist();
 InventoryItemMaint grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
 InventoryItem inv = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>.Select(grp, this.Base.Item.Current.InventoryCD.Trim());
 if (inv != null && inv.InventoryID.HasValue)
 {
    grp.Item.Current = grp.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(inv.InventoryID);
    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(grp, "Reloading Item");
 }
}
```

If you dont want the whole screen to be refreshed, instead of throwing the exception you can just refresh the required view method suggested by other user(Yura Zaletskyy) on this post.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your grid is binded to view PayRollsDetails. Then you can use following code to refresh your grid:

```
PayRollsDetails.View.Cache.Clear();
PayRollsDetails.View.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the select method.
For example: this is the item setting data view in Acumatica source code (you can use the explore source code page)

```
[PXViewName(Messages.InventoryItem)]
public PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>> ItemSettings;
```

Through customization (I assume you use AEF), add select method for this data view

```
[PXViewName(Messages.InventoryItem)]
public PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>> ItemSettings;

protected virtual IEnumerable itemSettings()
{
    return new PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>(Base).Select();
}
```

Sometimes I use sql store procedure to insert data to my table, the select method is helpful for reloading screen with inserted data.

Comment: Hi HDanh, 

im getting below error when publishing using your code
"error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'PX.Data.PXSelect>>>' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) in file: Code#InventoryItemMaint(36"

Comment: I've successfully published the project but unfortunately it does not solve the problem, i still need to reload the page to view the saved stock item.

Comment: Hmm, basically Acumatica recommends working with cache. I'll try another way based on your trigger but you can try this alternative solution:

Comment: do you need my trigger script?

Comment: Ok maybe I'm missing something here, let's clarify it: you created a new table, then by somehow map it to a new data view on Stock Item screen (General setting tab), then created trigger to insert data ?

Comment: no, I created a new table that is being populated by the trigger that i've put on the InventoryItem table of acumatica. the newly created table is not connected to acumatica and is in another database. Whenever the trigger is turned on, when saving new items in stock items screen of acumatica it does not display the last created items general settings tab. i need to reload the page so i can view the updated or the newly created stock item

Comment: it works well when the trigger is turned off, so i was searching for a code that will refresh the acumatica screen after saving.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll try to reproduce this case on my computer.

Comment: ok HDanh, thank you. Please update me if you have found the solution.